# Equivalent for DataGrid RowDetails template in Winforms DatagridView

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, datagrid, datagridview

I need to create an expander in my datagridview that adds additional info about that row to the datagridview when selected, and hides the same when collapsed.

This is possible by creating RowDetails templates in WPF, but can I do something similar in winforms datagridview? A workaround I'd thought of was dynamically adding objects to the datagridview on expand/collapse, but it won't work in this case because the number, type, arrangement of columns is very different for the details rows than the data rows.

Can RowTemplate possibly help? All examples I've seen thus far use rowtemplate only to fix height, width etc of rows in a datagridview and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ToolTip for selected row if you want to show additional data info.